# How to create a backwards compatible Swift pod?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I want to create a pod in Cocoapods using Swift 2.0

My code currently contains backwards-incompatible changes, like this one:

```
let index = array.indexOf(item)
```

This compiles in Swift 2.0, but in Swift 1.2 the 'indexOf' method is not avialable. In Swift 1.2, I still have to write:

```
let index = find(array, item)
```

How can I deal with these kinds of incompatibilities in my Cocoapods pod? Because I want both Swift 1.2 projects and Swift 2.0 projects to be able to include my pod.

How can this be done?

Comment: probably you'll need branches for every swift version